# Track user visits per web page

Tags: asp.net, session

I have different modules in my website and need to track how many times the user has visited each tab or module. Currently, I'm using Session variables to store the value and incrementing the counters on each visit on page_load event of the page and loading everything in the database on Session_End event. This seems to work when the user logs off from the application. But it doesn't seem to work when the user closes the browser or redirect to a different site. I thought the Session_End event would fire, no matter what, after the session time out period even if the browser is closed, but it doesn't seem to behave that way. Can anyone suggest a solution to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use Google Analytics (or similar) and save yourself the trouble?

Comment: Google analytics is nice for internet based apps.  He may be using an intranet app that might not be visible to the outside world.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm using intranet application. I don't know much about google analytics, I'll try to find something online. Could you point me to some article that explains google analytics if you have something? Thank you.

Comment: best place to get started; http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

The `Session_End` event should fire when the session expires, which will be some time after the user's last request to the server.

Remember that it's impossible for the server to know when the browser is closed.  (Unless you send an AJAX request in `onbeforeunload`)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is to use a custom [Profile](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/profile/default.aspx) object.  And, pertaining directly to your situation (using Profile vs Session), [here](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3520226/ASPNET-20-Profile-Simple-User-Personalization-for-Your-Web-Apps.htm) is a great article. A little modification, and you can use that code to track page views by which page is being viewed.  If you'd like to store this in Profile using a generic list, see [my blog post](http://jamesschubert.blogspot.com/2009/04/storing-generics-in-aspnet-profile.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea,

> You can create a webservice which gets called by client side code when
>   the user tries to close the browser. You can display a confirmation if he clicks 'yes', You can update your database, mark user as signed out & close the browser.
>   .